# Size limit of imported meshes in MeshLab

Tags: size, limit, mesh, meshlab

MeshLab crashes when importing a OBJ file larger than 10 MB.
Is there a size limit or a workaround?

Comment: No software should ever just _crash_. This is a bug that should be reported to the MeshLab developers.